# How can I know if specific parent React component exists?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So I've got a component that is dependent on the context of BrowserRouter to hook into

```html
<BrowserRouter>
  <...>
    <.../>
    <.../>
    <MyRedirectComponent/>
    <.../>
  </...>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I would love to simply include `BrowserRouter` inside my MyRedirectComponent that way I wouldn't need to wrap it all the time.

```js
const MyRedirectComponent = () => {

  const browserRouterParentExists = // I dunno

  return browserRouterParentExists ? (
      <NormalStuff/>
  ) : (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NormalStuff/>
    </BrowserRouter>  
  )
}
```

Is correctly populating `browserRouterParentExists` possible?

Comment: what is your end goal? Also without the parent child component won't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing conditional logic that tries to access parent component is an anti-pattern in React IMO and I don't think there is a public API you can use for that purpose.

I didn't get what you are trying to achieve but `BrowserRouter` is defined as

> A `<Router>` that uses the HTML5 history API (pushState, replaceState
> and the popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

and most of the time you only need one `BrowserRouter` in your app in a top level component like `App` considering its usage. So wrapping a component with it and using that component throughout your app is not quite reasonable. If you are trying to redirect user to another route based on some condition, you can use any data coming from *props, state, Context API* or a state management lib. like *Redux* etc. to implement your logic and render [Redirect](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect) component together with that conditional logic.